# ajax, добавление обьекта в html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет.

У меня есть html файл. в нем прописаны css стили.
Когда я через аякс (javascript) вставляю в html файл обьект, то к этому обьекту уже не действует css стиль.

Как то можно обновить стили?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что на этот объект могут действовать какие-то сторонние стили или не действуют стили из-за не правильного указания селекторов в CSS. А в ином случае, все стили абсолютно превосходно подхватываются генерируемыми объектами. И это я не предполагаю, а утверждаю.

Comment: Хм. Я этот обьект в ручную когда дописываю в файл сразу, то на него стиль действует.
Когда этот же обьект через аякс добавляется, то не действует.

Кривого ничего нету.

Comment: Тогда к событию, которое вызывает ajax, применяйте мтод live()